# Where do the exception predicates come from in Racket?

Tags: exception, racket

I've been trying to figure out how exceptions work in Racket, but I'm a bit puzzled on the exception predicates. To catch an exception of say `exn:fail` type, you test it with a predicate `exn:fail?` in a `with-handlers` expression. I've found [the documentation on `exn:fail`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._exn%7E3afail%29%29), but I don't see where `exn:fail?` is documented. Why I'm so curious about this is according to [this article](https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/errors-and-exceptions.html#exception-hacking), if you make a custom exception struct of say `exn:no-vowels`, you can still use `exn:no-vowels?` despite the fact that this predicate was never manually implemented. If I had to wager a guess, the predicate must have been generated automatically with a macro, but if so I'm curious to know where this "automatically generate predicates behavior" is documented and how the macro works exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exn` and derived exception types like the `exn:fail` hierarchy are all instances of Racket [structure types](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html), and predicates, constructors and accessors (like `exn-message`) are automatically defined when they're created with the [`struct`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html) macro.

User defined exception types can be exported from a module with [`struct-out`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-out%29%29) in a `provide` form, which exports all those generated functions without you having to list them manually.

Comment: Oh, I somehow totally forgot about the fact that structs generated those predicates thanks! Is there an implementation of `struct` I can look at, because that's really interesting?

Comment: It's somewhere in the racket source but I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: This is where the core functionality of `struct` is implemented: https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/racket/collects/racket/private/define-struct.rkt